# Dynamic search unable to show the result through selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

application consist dynamic search box &
while typing "Mumbai" search results drop down display as below,
[image]
But through selenium as,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2")).sendKeys("Mumbai"+ARROW_DOWN);
```

search result not display as, 
[image]

text box html as,

```
<input id="searchstr2" class="search ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" placeholder="Search for Building, Location or Developer" autocomplete="off" name="searchstr2" size="35" style="background-image: none;"
```

after successful search list display as,

```js
<li id="ui-id-117" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">
<a>
Nariman Point -
<b style="font-size:11px">
<span style="font-size:.8em; /*color:#EE7600;*/ color:#888888; float:right;">locality</span>
</a>
</li>
<li id="ui-id-118" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">
<li id="ui-id-119" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">
<li id="ui-id-120" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">
<li id="ui-id-121" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">
```

please suggest.

Comment: Could you share your website URL??

Comment: actually this functionality in backend of application so that its need credential for login. can i share html snap of same.

Comment: Actually without see live scenario it's hard to say what is the issue...

Comment: Try once as : `WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2"));el.click();el.sendKeys("Mumbai");`..and let me know..

Comment: thanks dear but not working.

Comment: Ok try once using `JavascriptExecutor` as : `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'Mumbai'", driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2")));`..and let me know..:)

Comment: hard luck its not working.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working???same behavior or anything else..??

Comment: same behavior i.e. just enter Mumbai but list not display.

Comment: try splitting up your search string into single character. In a loop send the character one by one. Enter the first character wait for the auto suggestion list to show up. Then the next character and so on. Maybe this works.

Comment: @Grasshopper any code snap or related reference.

Comment: For String to char array - toCharArray() method on String class. Use WebDriverWait and ExpectedCondition to check for visibility of auto-suggestion list. Just google the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java scripts takes some time to load the list so i have added timer in between send name & arrow down key event will be works for me code snap as,

```
WebElement ar=driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2"));
ar.sendKeys("Mumbai");
Thread.sleep(2000);
ar.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Comment: Worked for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the autocomplete fields is that usually there is a Javascript event that waits for text to be present in the field in order to display the available suggestions (could be Ajax that gets executed to get the suggestions from the server). `SendKeys` doesn't trigger that event, so you could try to click into the field after you've entered you're text. 
Basically:

```
WebElement suggestion = driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2"));
suggestion.sendKeys("Mumbai");
suggestion.click();
```

I didn't test this, so you could try using the `click()` method before `sendKeys()`.

If this doesn't fix your issue, you could try to do it by using Javascript to trigger your onChange event:

```
WebElement suggestion = driver.findElement(By.id("searchstr2"));
suggestion.click();
suggestion.sendKeys("Mumbai");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change(); return true;", suggestion);
```

Comment: thanks for help but above solution not working ( i.e. list not display) as per my observation while pressing down key instead of click, list will be displayed but "Keys.ARROW_DOWN" also not working. can you suggest according to this.